# Jquery/JS - how to Toggle the :after, :befor of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have the following question, how i can toggle the display of  :befor and :after of an element?

Here is the jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/swb6dxhy/

in the css you can see the

```
acc-btn:after, acc-btn:befor{display:[toggle this]} on line 19
```

Comment: What do you mean by toggle? If you put it in the css, it'll be there for good. Unless you override with javascript or a new class.

Comment: You can't do this, because, technically, the content of the pseudo classes ``:after`` and ``:before`` aren't part of the DOM. Of course, you can add and remove classes which have ``:after`` and ``:before`` in their CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set them always as `display:none`, and use a condition on the `#acc-btn` element, for example a class, to subject the visibility of the pseudo to having this class...

```
#acc-btn.show:after, #acc-btn.show:before {
    display: block;
}
```

Then, you can easily toggle this class on the main element:

```
$("#acc-btn").toggleClass("show");
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/swb6dxhy/1/)

Comment: this is perfectly fine, but i have a new problem i can only toggle the button with HTML, but in jsfiddle it works also with $("#acc-bn").on("click", function() {